# lockNow() DeviceAdmin not working on actual device

Tags: android, sms, locking

I am trying to do a lockNow() on receive a specified command from SMS. I have tested and it is working fine on my emulator (4.0.3) but when I tested on my actual device (4.2.2) and (4.1.2) and emulator of (4.2.2), it is not working.

It seem like it is not even receiving on on BroadcastReceiver for SMS.

Edit: It is working for my emulator (4.2.2) now, I actually forgot about RECEIVE_SMS permission in manifest earlier on when I pushed to 4.2.2 AVD. but it is still not working on my device.

Edit 2: I think that it might be due to 3rd party SMS application (e.g. GO SMS) which prevent my Broadcast from receiving the SMS first. I will probably try to uninstall GO SMS and see if it works.

Edit 3: It's really GO SMS. After hours of searching around, I just need to disable one of the settings in GO SMS. "Open Go SMS, hit 'Menu' and click 'Settings', click on 'Receive Settings', then uncheck the 'Disable other message notifications". And it works now! phew!

Hope it helps others in future.

This is my class for receiving the SMS and doing the lock action.

```
import android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class RemoteWipeSMS extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
    private static final String TAG = "SMSBroadcastReceiver";

    static final int WIPE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;

    DevicePolicyManager devicePolicyManager;


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         System.out.println("Test get SMS");
         Log.i(TAG, "not getting sms");
         Log.i(TAG, "Intent recieved: " + intent.getAction());
         devicePolicyManager = (DevicePolicyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);


            if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
                Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                if (bundle != null) {
                    Object[] pdus = (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
                    final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                    for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                        messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                    }
                    if (messages.length > -1) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Message recieved: " + messages[0].getMessageBody());
                        Toast.makeText(context, "SMS Received : "+messages[0].getMessageBody(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        if (messages[0].getMessageBody().equalsIgnoreCase("Lock")) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "SMS Action : To LOCKED",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            try {
                                devicePolicyManager.lockNow();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.e("Locked", "Lock error");
                            }
                        } else if (messages[0].getMessageBody().equalsIgnoreCase("Reset")) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "SMS Action : To Reset",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            try {
    devicePolicyManager.wipeData(WIPE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.e("Locked", "Reset error");
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
       }


}
```

Part of my manifest.

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo" >
        <service
            android:name="TestService">
        </service>

        <receiver 
            android:name="com.my.test.RemoteWipeSMS"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter
                android:priority="999" >
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <!-- This is where we register our receiver -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.my.test.DeviceAdminDetect"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN" >
            <intent-filter>

                <!-- This action is required -->
                <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- This is required this receiver to become device admin component. -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.device_admin"
                android:resource="@xml/device_admin" />
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name="com.my.test.Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: Did the user register the app as a device admin?

Comment: @323go yes! I tried reinstalling on my device and it's still not working as well.